# Alkyl halide addition

Tags: halides

[image]
For the above question....i did the usual addition of HF across double bonds and  joined both of them and.i thought the answer would be option(b) but the answer is something else please help!!

Comment: F- is a pretty bad nucleophile

Comment: So do you mean to say if it were a Cl/Br ....what i mentioned above would have happened?

Comment: yes, if this was an HBr reaction you would be correct.  The H-F bond is much stronger.  https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/alkenes/hhal.html

Comment: Thank you so much... they have given option c as an answer....could you explain the  way it has attained

Comment: Hi thanks i found the link...https://books.google.co.in/books?dq=Benzene+reacts+with+Cyclohexene+in+the+presence+of+HF&hl=en&id=0X4cQus2gz8C&pg=PA285&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicmpjh0NzVAhVCO48KHQo2AHMQ6AEIJzAA

Comment: HF is just there to release H+ to protonate the cyclohexene...and the carbocation so formed will be used for EAS on benzene...and so (c) will be the answer...your welcome